# Meteor subscribe sending to much data

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I have subscribed to a collection with Meteor, and passing a page number to allow pagination. The limit parameter is set to 15 so no more than 15 docs should ever be returned, however when I switch page number the subscription returns 3 consecutive times with 15, 30 then 15 docs again. Only the last being the correct 15.

Because of this the UI sees a "flash" as the table data grows to 30 rows then back to 15 again.

I am using react for the UI and containing a component like so to pass data as props to the render component:

```
export default createContainer(props => {

    // Get collection name from router/url and grab mongo collection
    let collectionName = props.routeParams.collectionId;
    let Collection = CollectionData(collectionName).collection;

    // Get paged results based on URL query page
    Meteor.subscribe(collectionName, props.location.query.page || 1);

    return {
        items: Collection.find({}, {sort: {createdAt: -1}}).fetch(),
        total: Collection.find({}).count()
    };

}, Collection);
```

In the render component I update the router history state, to change the page number like ?page=1. This causes the re-render which will update the value of "props.location.query.page" allowing the subscription data to change. I am not sure if there is a better way to change the pagination value.

The publish code looks like:

```
// Publish data
if(Meteor.isServer) {
    Meteor.publish(mongoCollectionName, function(page){
        if(page) {
            let pageSize = 15;
            page = parseInt(page)-1;
            if(page < 0) page = 0;
            return collection.find({}, {limit: pageSize, skip: page*pageSize});
        } else {
            return collection.find({});
        }
    });
}
```

From what I can see it seems meteor is joining the two arrays of 15 to make the array of 30 docs, at some point before my component receives the data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use template level subscriptions instead of global subscriptions to prevent multiple subscriptions for the same data, this should solve your problem.

Inside your onCreated function for your template call `this.subscribe("nameOfSub", params)` where nameOfCollection is the name of your subscription and params are any params you pass in.

Use the `{{Template.subscriptionsReady}}` helper to detect when template subscriptions are ready.

Comment: I think this is only applicable to blaze? How can this be implemented with react?